# Python / Azure Event Hubs

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

I'm putting together a very basic Python script which suppose to send a sample JSON data to Azure Event Hubs.
Here is my script:

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient

async def send_json_message(connection_string, event_hub_name, json_message):
  """Sends a JSON message to an Azure Event Hub.

  Args:
    connection_string: The connection string to your Azure Event Hubs namespace.
    event_hub_name: The name of your event hub.
    json_message: The JSON message to send.
  """

  producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, event_hub_name)

  async with producer:
    event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()
    event_data_batch.add(EventData(body=json.dumps(json_message)))
    await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  connection_string = "Endpoint=sb://auditblobevents.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=k9GhYMwABTBa6PuHKczIolE7FJeR0bOpQ+AEhEgMAY8="
  event_hub_name = "auditblobtopic"
  json_message = {
    "id": 1234567890,
    "name": "Peter",
    "message": "This is a JSON message."
  }

  asyncio.run(send_json_message(connection_string, event_hub_name, json_message))
```

When I run this script ("python3 send.py"), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 29, in <module>
    asyncio.run(send_json_message(connection_string, event_hub_name, json_message))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "send.py", line 13, in send_json_message
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, event_hub_name)
TypeError: from_connection_string() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am not a Python developer, but I can only see 2 parameters being passed to "from_connection_string()"

What can I change to get passed this issue?

Comment: FYI you should remove the shared access key if that's your real one and not an example one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the incorrect usage of the `EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string` method.

- I tried the below code from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=passwordless%2Croles-azure-portal#send-events).

```py
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
import json
# Azure Event Hubs configuration
CONNECTION_STRING = "   "
EVENT_HUB_NAME = " "

# Create a sample JSON message
json_message = {
    "id": 1234567890,
    "name": "Peter",
    "message": "This is a JSON message."
}

async def send_json_message():
    # Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub using the connection string.
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING, eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME)
    
    try:
        async with producer:
            # Create a batch.
            event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()

            # Add the JSON message to the batch.
            event_data_batch.add(EventData(body=json.dumps(json_message)))

            # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
            await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

        # Print a success message and display the sent JSON message.
        print("Message sent successfully:")
        print(json.dumps(json_message, indent=4))

    except Exception as e:
        # Print an error message and the exception when sending fails.
        print("Failed to send message:")
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(send_json_message())
```

[image]

[image]